# How do i get my js function to add to cart items from two different lists same menu of products?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

Here is the item list in ejs format i have divided the list into two, one list is for snacks and the other one is meant to be a list for drinks, when i add items in the snacks list they add to cart and even calculate the total but when i try the adding items on the drinks list nothing happens, i have provided my js function for adding items to cart down below

```
 <!--SNACKS LSIT-->
    <div class="banner-snacks">Snacks</div>
        <div class="list">     
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/1.PNG" alt="Chicken Wings">
        <div class="title">Chicken Wings</div>
        <div class="price">450.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(1)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/2.PNG" alt="Dry Fry Fish">
        <div class="title">Dry Fry Fish</div>
        <div class="price">650.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(2)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/3.PNG" alt="Fries Masala">
        <div class="title">Fries Masala</div>
        <div class="price">250.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(3)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/4.PNG" alt="Fries">
        <div class="title">Fries</div>
        <div class="price">250.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(4)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/5.PNG" alt="Pork Pan Fry">
        <div class="title">Pork Pan Fry</div>
        <div class="price">650.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(5)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="images/6.PNG" alt="Kales">
        <div class="title">Kales</div>
        <div class="price">100.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(6)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
        </div>
        <!--DRINKS LIST-->
    <div class="banner-drinks">
        <div>
            <div class="banner-drink">Drinks</div>
          </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="list-drinks">
     <div class="item-drinks">
        <img src="images/7.PNG" alt="Kuku Kienyeji">
        <div class="title">Kuku Kienyeji</div>
        <div class="price">450.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(7)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>   
    <div class="item-drinks">
        <img src="images/8.PNG" alt="Ugali">
        <div class="title">Ugali</div>
        <div class="price">50.00</div>
        <button onclick="addToCart(8)">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
```

And here is the function but it only calculates for the snacks list and not drinks list

```
//menu calculating and adding function.
function addToCart(key) {
    console.log('Key value:', key);

    let item = list.querySelectorAll('.item')[key - 1];
    let name = item.querySelector('.title').textContent;
    let priceText = item.querySelector('.price').textContent;
    let price = parseFloat(priceText.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
    

    let container;
    if (key < 6) {
        container = listCarts; // Snacks container
    } else {
        container = listCartsDrinks; // Drinks container
    }

    
    if (listCarts[key] == null) {
        // copy product info to list card
        listCarts[key] = {
            name: name,
            basePrice: price,
            price: price,
            quantity: 1,
        };
    } else {
        listCarts[key].quantity++;
        listCarts[key].price = listCarts[key].basePrice * listCarts[key].quantity;
    }

    reloadCart();
}
```

I have tried modifying the function to look this way but still hasn't worked

```
if (key < 6) {
        item = document.querySelectorAll('.item')[key - 1];
    } else {
        item = document.querySelectorAll('.item-drinks')[key - 7];
    }
```

Comment: `let item = list.querySelectorAll('.item')` will not select from the drinks list

Comment: With your attempt to fix the issue, you would either select the first six items, or the last two - but your `[key - 1]` would still be off then. (You pass `8` for the second drinks item, so you would be trying to access item number "seven minus one" out of only _two_ items here then.) Just fix the selector, so that it selects _both_ types of items - `let item = list.querySelectorAll('.item, .item-drinks')[key - 1];`

Comment: even after adding .item-drinks to the selector it still won't add the drinks list to cart.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing HTML structure, you need to create drinks elements container separately, and assign `item` according to the key value instead, and also reduce the key by the length of snacks when selecting `item`.

Try this:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const listDrinks = document.querySelector('.list-drinks');

const listCarts = [];
const listCartsDrinks = [];

//menu calculating and adding function.
function addToCart(key) {

  let item;
  let container;

  if (key <= 6) {

    item = list.querySelectorAll('.item')[key - 1];
    container = listCarts; // Snacks container

  } else {

    item = listDrinks.querySelectorAll('.item-drinks')[(key - 6) - 1];
    container = listCartsDrinks; // Drinks container
  }


  let name = item.querySelector('.title').textContent;
  let priceText = item.querySelector('.price').textContent;
  let price = parseFloat(priceText.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));


  if (container[key] == null) {
    // copy product info to list card
    container[key] = {
      name: name,
      basePrice: price,
      price: price,
      quantity: 1,
    };
  } else {
    container[key].quantity++;
    container[key].price = container[key].basePrice * container[key].quantity;
  }

  console.log('snacks', listCarts, '\ndrinks', listCartsDrinks);
  reloadCart();
}

function reloadCart() {
  console.log('reloadCart');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 20% !important;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!--SNACKS LSIT-->
<div class="banner-snacks">Snacks</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/1.PNG" alt="Chicken Wings">
    <div class="title">Chicken Wings</div>
    <div class="price">450.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(1)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/2.PNG" alt="Dry Fry Fish">
    <div class="title">Dry Fry Fish</div>
    <div class="price">650.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(2)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/3.PNG" alt="Fries Masala">
    <div class="title">Fries Masala</div>
    <div class="price">250.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(3)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/4.PNG" alt="Fries">
    <div class="title">Fries</div>
    <div class="price">250.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(4)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/5.PNG" alt="Pork Pan Fry">
    <div class="title">Pork Pan Fry</div>
    <div class="price">650.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(5)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/6.PNG" alt="Kales">
    <div class="title">Kales</div>
    <div class="price">100.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(6)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--DRINKS LIST-->
<div class="banner-drinks">
  <div>
    <div class="banner-drink">Drinks</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-drinks">
  <div class="item-drinks">
    <img src="images/7.PNG" alt="Kuku Kienyeji">
    <div class="title">Kuku Kienyeji</div>
    <div class="price">450.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(7)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item-drinks">
    <img src="images/8.PNG" alt="Ugali">
    <div class="title">Ugali</div>
    <div class="price">50.00</div>
    <button onclick="addToCart(8)">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But that's not practical, so the code could be improved.

So, I'd add `cart-item` class to each item, and distinct them by their current classes, and use event listeners instead of `onclick`, and assign them to each button, and there assign each button an index/ID dynamically, which would be passed to click listener, and then in the click listener assign button's parent as item, and also use object instead of an array for items store, to avoid empty array elements, while preserving element's index:

```js
// get all items
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-item');

// add click listener
// also attach item index 1-8
document.querySelectorAll('.cart-item button').forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.id = ++i;
  btn.addEventListener('click', addToCart);
});

// containers
const listCarts = {};
const listCartsDrinks = {};

//menu calculating and adding function.
function addToCart(e) {

  // item is button container with all the data
  const item = e.target.parentElement;
  // get its index 1-8
  const key = e.currentTarget.id;

  let container;

  // determin is it snack or drink by its' class
  if (item.classList.contains('item')) {

    container = listCarts; // Snacks container

  } else {

    container = listCartsDrinks; // Drinks container
  }


  let name = item.querySelector('.title').textContent;
  let priceText = item.querySelector('.price').textContent;
  let price = parseFloat(priceText.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));


  if (container[key] == null) {
    // copy product info to list card
    container[key] = {
      name: name,
      basePrice: price,
      price: price,
      quantity: 1,
    };
  } else {
    container[key].quantity++;
    container[key].price = container[key].basePrice * container[key].quantity;
  }

  console.log('snacks', listCarts, '\ndrinks', listCartsDrinks);
  reloadCart();
}

function reloadCart() {
  console.log('reloadCart');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 20% !important;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!--SNACKS LSIT-->
<div class="banner-snacks">Snacks</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="cart-item item">
    <img src="images/1.PNG" alt="Chicken Wings">
    <div class="title">Chicken Wings</div>
    <div class="price">450.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item item">
    <img src="images/2.PNG" alt="Dry Fry Fish">
    <div class="title">Dry Fry Fish</div>
    <div class="price">650.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item item">
    <img src="images/3.PNG" alt="Fries Masala">
    <div class="title">Fries Masala</div>
    <div class="price">250.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item item">
    <img src="images/4.PNG" alt="Fries">
    <div class="title">Fries</div>
    <div class="price">250.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item item">
    <img src="images/5.PNG" alt="Pork Pan Fry">
    <div class="title">Pork Pan Fry</div>
    <div class="price">650.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item item">
    <img src="images/6.PNG" alt="Kales">
    <div class="title">Kales</div>
    <div class="price">100.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--DRINKS LIST-->
<div class="banner-drinks">
  <div>
    <div class="banner-drink">Drinks</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-drinks">
  <div class="cart-item item-drinks">
    <img src="images/7.PNG" alt="Kuku Kienyeji">
    <div class="title">Kuku Kienyeji</div>
    <div class="price">450.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item item-drinks">
    <img src="images/8.PNG" alt="Ugali">
    <div class="title">Ugali</div>
    <div class="price">50.00</div>
    <button>Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```